# Pegar valor do mês de uma lista

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Preciso que a pessoa possa obter as informações e mês que ela desejar, assim preciso pegar essas informações na lista e depois mostrar a placa, data, horário de entrada e saída, valor pago e total do mês. Estava tentando com um `Split()` mas não consegui.

```
public class Informacao2
{
    public string placa { get; set; }
    public float precoHora { get; set; }
    public DateTime entrada { get; set; }
}
class Ex3
{
    Informacao2 novaInformacao = new Informacao2();
    List<Informacao2> informacoes = new List<Informacao2>();
    List<Informacao2> mostraVeicMes = new List<Informacao2>();
    public void Executar()
    {
        int opcao = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Cadastrar Entrada de Veiculo");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Cadastrar Saida do Veiculo");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Mostrar Veiculos Estacionados no Mês");
            Console.WriteLine("0 - Sair");
            opcao = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (opcao)
            {
                case 0: break;
                case 1:
                    CadastraEntradaEPrecoVeiculo();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    CadastraSaidaVeiculo();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    MostraVeiculoEstcionadoMes();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Opção inválida");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
            }
        } while (opcao != 0);
    }
    public void CadastraEntradaEPrecoVeiculo()
    {
        DateTime ent;
        string data1;
        bool f1;
        Console.Write("Informe o preço da hora: ");
        novaInformacao.precoHora = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Informe a data e hora de entrada do automóvel dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
            data1 = Console.ReadLine();
            f1 = DateTime.TryParseExact(data1, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out ent);
            if (f1 == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Formato Inválido!");
            }
        } while (f1 == false);
        novaInformacao.entrada = ent;
        Console.Write("Informe a placa do veículo: ");
        novaInformacao.placa = Console.ReadLine();
        novaInformacao.placa = novaInformacao.placa.ToUpper();
        informacoes.Add(novaInformacao);
        mostraVeicMes.Add(novaInformacao);
    }
    private void MostrarInformacoes()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        foreach (Informacao2 informacao in informacoes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Placa: {novaInformacao.placa}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Preço da hora: {novaInformacao.precoHora}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Horario de entrada: {novaInformacao.entrada.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")}");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
    public void CadastraSaidaVeiculo()
    {
        MostrarInformacoes();
        DateTime atual;
        Console.Write("Informe a placa do veículo: ");
        string placaInformada = Console.ReadLine();
        List<Informacao2> placaencontrada = informacoes.Where(c => c.placa.ToUpper().Contains(placaInformada.ToUpper())).ToList();
        atual = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan tempoEst = atual - novaInformacao.entrada;
        double valorvaloraserpago = Math.Ceiling(tempoEst.Hours * novaInformacao.precoHora);
        foreach (Informacao2 informacao in placaencontrada)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"PLACA ENCONTRADA: {informacao.placa}");
            Console.WriteLine($"VALOR A SER PAGO {valorvaloraserpago}");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public void MostraVeiculoEstcionadoMes()
    {
        /*d) Mostrar um Relatório de veículos estacionados no mês (na tela)
       - Solicitar o mês para o usuário
       - Mostrar a placa, data e horário de entrada, data e horário de saída e valor pago e o
       total do mês.*/
        Int32 pegaMes,compare=0;
        Console.Write("Informe o mês que deseja o relatório com 2 digitos: ");
        pegaMes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        foreach (Informacao2 informacao in informacoes)
        {
            string m = novaInformacao.entrada.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            string[] mes = m.Split('/');
            pegaMes = Convert.ToInt32(mes[1]);
            compare = Convert.ToInt32(mes[1]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o linq ? informacoes.Where(d=> d.entrada.Month == novaInformacao.entrada.Month); se você precisar só comparar uso o Any no lugar do Where

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Tem vários problemas nesse código, mas o que você quer é mais simples do que parece. Basta pedir o mês na própria data, não tem que fazer malabarismos.

```
mes = novaInformacao.entrada.Month;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/GetNested.cs).

Sempre [consulte a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.month?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_DateTime_Month) para ver se já não tem pronto o que deseja. E quase toda conversão de tipo realizada indica que o código tem algum problema.